# jQuery select value switches to default on change

Tags: jquery

my code is here http://jsfiddle.net/2BcS3/

```
$("#b").click(function(){
 //should output: [user selection] - []
 alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 


 $("#i").val('nice');    
 //should output: [user selection] - [nice]
 alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 

 //should output: [nice] - [nice]
 $("#s").val($("#i").val());
 alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 
});
```

and the html

```
<select id='s'>
 <option value='0'>select</option>
 <option value='1'>ok</option>
 <option value='2'>no</option>
</select>
<input id='i' type='hidden' />
<button type='button' id='b'>go</button>
```

you will notice the issue right away. I am trying to change the value of the select to what has been input in a hidden field dynamically. For some reason the select does not take in the new value and switches automatically to the first value of the select list !!!

Comment: `i` doesn't have a value, how can you set `s`?

Comment: s is set by selecting and changed after you click the button and i are set when you click the button. check jsfiddle

Comment: but `i` is a string and `s` has optional values of 0,1,2

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your trying to force the select to have a value that doesn't exist within it's options, if you add `<option value='nice'>nice!</option>` to the select, your code will work...

[**<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/FpRgd/)

Comment: that's the point. I am trying to force a value to the select. this value is not on the list and it is from a different input. by using what @Lochemage suggested you are attaching/changing the value of the selected option to the new value from the input field

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the currently selected option, not just the value of the 'select' element.

```
$("#s :selected").val();
```

Your script should look more like this:

```
$("#b").click(function(){
    //should output: [user selection] - []
    alert("[" + $("#s :selected").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 


    $("#i").val('nice');
    //should output: [user selection] - [nice]
    alert("[" + $("#s :selected").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 

    //should output: [nice] - [nice]
    $("#s :selected").val($("#i").val());
    alert("[" + $("#s :selected").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 
});
```

Comment: that's it. thank you so much that's been driving me nuts for the last 5 hours

Answer (score 0):

Try `option:selected`, like:

```
$("#b").click(function(){
  //should output: [user selection] - []
  alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 


  $("#i").val('nice');    
  //should output: [user selection] - [nice]
  alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 

  //should output: [nice] - [nice]
  $("#s option:selected").attr('value', $("#i").val());
  alert("[" + $("#s").val() + "] - [" + $("#i").val() + "]"); 
});
```

I updated your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/2BcS3/3/ .